# How to hide hours line in Full Calendar

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

I have this agenda view and I want to hide the hours line. What's the solution ? Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use basicWeek instead of agendaWeek view [available views](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/views/Available_Views/)

check this: http://jsfiddle.net/e78b944d/1/

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  defaultView: 'basicWeek' /* 'agendaWeek' */
});
```

Comment: The problem is, that I want ressource view and it's only available in agendaWeek

Comment: you can use **groupByResource** property.

    `views: {
            basicWeek:{
                groupByResource: true
           }
       }`

Comment: I found a solution with CSS :      table tr:nth-child(3) {
     display: none;
 }